# is there an event/signal which happens when the QMdiarea become empty?

Tags: c++, qt, events, qt5, qt-signals

I want to implement a code when `QMdiarea` is empty i.e. (has no `QSubWindow` children).

For example:

[image]

[image]

is there an event or signal which happens when the `QMdiarea` become empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `QMdiArea::subWindowActivated(QMdiSubWindow *window)` signal to track the mentioned state. As [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdiarea.html#subWindowActivated) say, when `window` parameter is null means the last MDI child window is closed and the workspace is empty.

Comment: This is false. As docs say, window parameter will be null when there's no active child window. You can call `QMdiArea.setActiveSubWindow(nullptr)` to have this signal emitted with nullptr window.